# How to make a Hidden Element Not Required

Tags: javascript, html, webforms, element

I have a hidden element (submit form) if the user selects No to the radio button and I am wondering if there is a way to make it so the element is not required when it is hidden but then to required when it is not. Any ideas?

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br>
        <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" required /><br>
        <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
        <input class="lname" type="text" required/><br>
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input class="email" type="text" required/><br>
        <input type="radio" name="file" value="yes" id="yes" onclick="handleChange(false);" />
        <label for="Yes">Yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="file" value="no" id="no" onclick="handleChange(true);" />
        <label for="No">No</label><br>
        <p><input type="file" size="30" id="fileUpload" ></p>
    </form>

    <script>
        function validateForm() {
            window.open("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
        }

        function handleChange(remove) {
            var element = document.getElementById('fileUpload');
            if (remove)
                element.style.display = 'none';
            else 
                element.style.display = 'block';
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Where is the hidden element in form?

Comment: @brk the hidden element is the file upload. It becomes hidden based on the JavaScript function if the user selects No to the radio button.

Comment: i dont quite understand it. u r saying that if your file upload is hidden then u dont want it to be required right?

Comment: @ZimCxx Yes. If the user chooses not to upload the file then I want to make that option not required.

Comment: have you tried doing `element.required = true;` and `element.required = false;` in your `handleChange` function?

Answer (score 2):

Disabling the element will cause the required tag to be ignored.

```
element.disabled = true;
```